# Struts 2 Passing Parameter with dot in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, struts2

I can pass parameter in Struts 2 (GAE app) Url something like below:

```
http://localhost:8888/user/jr
http://localhost:8888/user/jr@jrgalia
```

But i got an error for

```
http://localhost:8888/user/jr@jrgalia.com
```

How to allow to pass parameter with dot character?

Below is in struts.xml

```
....
<constant name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="true"/>
<constant name="struts.mapper.alwaysSelectFullNamespace" value="false"/>
...
<action name="/user/*" class="LinkAction" method="usersLink">
<param name="userName">{1}</param>
    <result>
    <param name="location">/index.jsp</param>
    <param name="parse">false</param>
        <param name="encode">false</param>
    </result>
</action>
```

Below is the error:

```
HTTP ERROR 404
Problem accessing /user/jr@jrgalia.com. Reason:
   NOT_FOUND
Powered by Jetty://
```

Comment: Please add the exception message

Comment: Have you tried with `jr%40jrgalia.com`?, encoded URL.

Comment: I think the problem is not on '@' sign, it's in .com

Comment: I have a same issue and work around by adding a slash '/' at the end of the url. But it looks pretty ugly. Hope it helps. If you found a real solution please let me know.